# Show the file names side by side and fix the window size

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on Angular.js and bootstrap CSS. I am trying to fix the height of the window, when multiple files are uploaded by clicking on `Upload file` button the size of the window is also getting increased, I want to show the selected files name side by side instead of showing each file name in different lines(shown currently in the demo) when files are selected and want to fix the window size, when more files are uploaded can we show the scroll bar only at file names instead of increasing the window size?

DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/enIZfA1hYD23vvSWn2NJ?p=preview

sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalInstanceCtrl">
  <form name="headerForm">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <br>
          <div> <input type="file" id="fileUpload" ng-file-model="files" multiple />
            <div class="btn"><span id='button' ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();clickOnUpload();">Upload File</span></div>
            <span ng-if="filesToUpload.length > 0">{{filesToUpload.length}} file<span ng-if="filesToUpload.length > 1">s</span> selected</span>
            <p ng-repeat="file in filesToUpload track by $index">
              {{file.name}} <span class="delete-file" ng-click="deleteFile($index)">X</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <textarea rows="20" maxlength=35000 name="message" ng-model="message"></textarea>
          <button type="button" ng-click="cancelModal()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The `ng-file-model` directive is not a core AngularJS directive. Please don't use the `ng-` prefix for custom directives. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core AngularJS directives.

Comment: “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How do you want that it will look? Is it https://i.stack.imgur.com/sij5W.png?

Comment: @Mosh Feu - yes, as you shown in the image and when files are more currently it is showing the scroll bar for the entire page at right hand side instead of that I just want to show the scroll bar for that files list shown so that it won’t increase the page size.

Comment: I don't understand the scroll thing. What do you mean? Can you sketch the look you want? Even with paint app or something..